# Sony WF 1000MX3 vs Oneplus Buds Pro

Tags: wireless, headphones, headset, earphones, audio-quality

As you can know on 2/10/2021, price of Oneplus Buds pro and Sony WF 1000MX3 are similar on amazon.in which is around ₹10,000. I'm confused which one to buy.

My preference:

1. Sound Quality (For music)
2. ANC (active noise cancellation)
3. Call quality (in outdoors)

I searched on internet, some says that Sony's audio quality is very poor (compared to audio technica, cheap (~ ₹2,000) boat earbuds). Can you please suggest me which one should I buy to get better sound and call quality.

Can you please suggest me good TWS around ₹10,000?

p.s.- Please don't go for brand and their specifications.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at AirPods Pro?  They're around ₹4,800 more, but they have excellent audio/microphone quality as well as very good noise cancelling/transparency mode. They don't even require an iPhone, you can use them on android.  If you want good TWS headphones, this is what I would get.

Comment: It's ₹17,990. too costly for me. I want under ₹10,000.